# Jquery getting val() inside TextAreaFor()

Tags: c#, jquery

I know this is simple and I am probably only missing something small but I am looking to get the text from a `TextAreaFor` in JQuery,

C#

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Name, new { cols = 50, rows = 3, @class = "txtName" })
```

I have tried

JQuery / Javascript

```
alert($('.txtName-textarea').val());
alert($('.txtName').val());
alert($('.txtName textarea').val());
alert($('.txtName input').val());
```

I know I will probably look silly, but I rather know how to do it now, rather then in an hour and still feel silly.

Thanks

Comment: What is the HTML that is rendered?

Comment: We could need to see the `HTML` rendered by that `server-side` piece of code. Just harvest it from our browser.

Comment: is the javascript actually on the page itself, or in a separate file which is referenced on the page? If the second, have you checked if it was cached?

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about looking at the HTML in firebug etc etc, I will look on there - and this should tell me the problem(s)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run fine.

```js
alert($(".txtName").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="txtName">some text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that one individual text area, this should work:

```
alert($('#Name').val());   // #Name is the elementId
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Name, new { cols = 50, rows = 3, @class = "txtName" })
```

renders to:

```
 <textarea class="txtName" cols="50" rows="50"></textarea>
```

I assume that you are importing jQuery in your webapp, somehow, so that $('SOMETHING') resolves to something... then the query should be:

```
$('textarea.txtName').val() //should return the val of EVERY ENTRY of this node
```

I do not know whats the purpose of getting the val throughout jQuery, but if it is involved with the business model maybe you could do it in an Action in your Controller,

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

i hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".txtName").html();
```

or

```
$(".txtName").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your all suggestions, however I took the advice to see the rendered HTML and use the ID that was assigned to the texaarea element. For those who need to know how to do this, if you go to IE, right click on your html page and click "View source" then bingo.

Comment: SO won't let me accept the answer until tomorrow so I may forget to accept, however, the other answers will help you too